# Move contents of div to another div that has a matching data attribute value using Jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to move the contents of a div `module-score` to another div `module-progress` when the data attribute values match.

I've made the following attempt below but it doesn't seem to move anything, where am I going wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.module-score').each(function(i, obj) {
        var score = $(this).data('completion');
        var contents = $(this).contents();

        $('.module-progress[data-progress="' + score + '"]').appendTo(contents);

    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're using `appendTo()` when you wanted to be using `append()`

```
var one = $(/*...*/);
var two = $(/*...*/);

one.append(two); // Adds two to one.
one.appendTo(two); // Adds one to two.
```

Comment: @Rob it's always the simple things that mess us up ^_^